# Redux combineReducer using Flow and flow-typed for redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, flow-typed

I've got two reducers in the app combined with combine reducer (reducer.js).

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export const reducers = {
    search: searchReducer,
    table: tableReducer
};

export const reducer = combineReducer(reducers);
```

Also I have a snippet to automatically parse store types from reducers (from [this Medium post](https://blog.callstack.io/type-checking-react-and-redux-thunk-with-flow-part-2-206ce5f6e705)) using Store from flow-typed redux_v3.x.x.js

```
import { reducers } from './reducer';

type Reducers = typeof reducers;

type $ExtractFunctionReturn = <V>(v: (...args: any) => V) => V;
export type State = $ObjMap<Reducers, $ExtractFunctionReturn>;

export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Actions>;
```

And I got an error from flow-typed CombinedReducer that it can't find reducers (search and table).

```
src/types.js:65
65: export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Actions>;
                                ^^^^^ property `search`. Property not 
found in
54:   declare function combineReducers<O: Object, A>(reducers: O): 
CombinedReducer<$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>, A>;

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: flow-
typed/npm/redux_v3.x.x.js:54

src/types.js:65
65: export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Actions>;
                                ^^^^^ property `table`. Property not 
found in
54:   declare function combineReducers<O: Object, A>(reducers: O): 
CombinedReducer<$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>, A>;

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: flow-
typed/npm/redux_v3.x.x.js:54
```

How to solve that error and make my Store working correct with Flow?

Before that error I got another one

```
Flow: object map. This type is incompatible with union: Intersection 
type | undefined.
flow-typed/redux_v3.x.x.js
30: declare type CombinedReducer<S, A> = (state: $Shape<S> & {} | void
```

And I have added Object type to declare type CombinedReducer (actually I don't think I should edit flow-typed and in the Medium example there is no such an error):

```
declare type CombinedReducer<S, A> = (state: $Shape<S> & {} | Object | void
```

I suppose these errors can be caused by the same thing.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I’m using typescript.

Comment: Can you post all code of reducers on https://flow.org/try/ ?